# Django unit-testing client.login not working

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using django 1.6 and I have the following test code:

```
def tes_stuff(self):
    new_user=EndUser.objects.create(username="test", firstname="test", email="t@t.com", password="test")
    self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username="test", password="test"))
```

When I run it I get an arror that says:

```
AssertionError: False is not true
```

I am unsure why it is not logging the user in. Perhaps it has to do with the password? EndUser is a model I created, but it extends from the normal user model in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think i solved it, I added a save:

```
def tes_stuff(self):
    new_user=EndUser.objects.create(username="test", firstname="test", email="t@t.com", password="test")
    new_user.save()
    self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username="test", password="test"))
```

It seems that this fixed it, I dont get errors now.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the *create_user* method. Link to the docs: [create_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)